# How to update form content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am making a web application using asp.net mvc 3.

There is a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Approvals</legend>
        <div>
            @Html.Label("Ticket ID")
            @Html.DropDownList("TicketID")
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.Label("Distributor ID")
            @Html.TextBox("DistributorID", null, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.Label("Description")
            @Html.TextArea("Description", new { @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.Label("Resolved")
            @Html.DropDownList("Resolved")
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.Label("Date (yyyy/mm/dd)")
            @Html.TextBox("Date")
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.Label("Time (HH:mm:ss)")
            @Html.TextBox("Time")
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Approve / Disapprove" />
</div>
}
```

How can I update the data of other fields after reading values from database whenever a ticket id is selected from TicketID dropdownlist. i.e. whenever a ticket id is changed, accordingly data in other fields should change after reading data from database of particular ticket id, without submitting the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using ajax:

```
$('select[name=TicketID]').change(function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $.getJSON('/mycontroller/MyAction', selectedValue,
    function(result){
        $('input[name=DistributorID]').val(result.DistributorID);
        $('input[name=Description]').val(result.Description);
        $('input[name=Resolved]').val(result.Resolved);
        $('input[name=Date]').val(result.Date);
        $('input[name=Time]').val(result.Time);
    });
});
```

In Controller:

```
public JsonResult MyAction(int selectedValue)
{
    var result = new
    {
        DistributorID = 1,
        Description = 1,
        Resolved= 1,
        Date= 1,
        Time= 1
    };
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavour.AllowGet);
}
```

Sorry for syntax errors I may have, I have written the code directly here

Answer (score 0):

You could call an action that returns json result by jquery ajax post.

the action returns something you want.

```
$('#TicketID').change(function(){
   $.ajax({
     url: '/ActionThatReturnsJsonResult',
     cache: false,
     type: 'post'
     success: function (data) {
         $('#DistributorID').val(data.DistributorIDFromDataBase);
     },
     error: function (e) {
         alert(e.responseText);                            
     }
   });
});
```